# String will not split using Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js

As seen in the snippet, I have a Regex that *should* identify any empty lines. (I'm aware I can just do /n/n, but it doesn't suit my purposes). I've tested it in a word editor, and it picks up every new line when using the find tool. But in JS, I'm still getting the entire file. What am I missing, here?

```js
const mockData = `This is some fake data
with multiple sentences
  
and line breaks`;

const newArr = mockData.split(/^\s*$/);

console.log(newArr[0]);
```

Comment: You have a multiline string but aren't using the `m` (multiline) flag. You probably also want the `g` (global) flag

Comment: `const newArr = mockData.split(/\s*$/m);` works for me

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiline string but aren't using the `m` (multiline) flag. Without it `^` and `$` match the start/end of the *entire* string, so you'd only split if the entirety of the string was composed of whitespace:

```js
//multiline - all whitespace
const mockData = `
 
`;

const newArr = mockData.split(/^\s*$/);

console.log(newArr);
```

Using the `m` flag, the `^` and `$` characters instead match start/end of *each line*. So now the regex works to split on lines that are either empty or composed of newline characters:

```js
const mockData = `This is some fake data
with multiple sentences
  
and line breaks`;

const newArr = mockData.split(/^\s*$/m);

console.log(newArr);
```

If you intend to split at newlines *and* empty lines leaving no blanks, then you can eschew the `^` and `$` characters entirely, since they are actually more trouble. The engine might do a split *before* a newline because that's the end of the line `$`. So, instead of trying to get around that with more regex, just split on whitespace + a newline or newline + whitespace.

```js
const mockData = `This is some fake data
with multiple sentences
  
and line breaks`;

const newArr = mockData.split(/\s*[\r\n]+|[\r\n]+\s*/);

console.log(newArr);
```

With this you don't need to use the multiline flag, since you never use the behaviour it introduces.

Also, I should note that  `[\r\n]+` is a slight cheat on my part. The end of line characters are either `\r\n` or just `\n`, you very likely will never encounter a simple `\r`. However, the *proper* regex then is `\r?\n` which I find ugly, especially if you try to repeat it - `(\r?\n)+`. A character class is ever so slightly inaccurate yet in a way that should never have any effect on accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [multiline flag](https://javascript.info/regexp-multiline-mode) works better

`const newArr = mockData.split(/\s*$/m);`

Take your pick

```js
const re1 = /^\s*|\s*$/m
const re2 = /^\s*$/m
const re3 = /\s*$/m

const mockData = `This is some fake data
with multiple sentences

and line breaks`;

const newArr1 = mockData.split(re1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr1))
const newArr2 = mockData.split(re2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr2))
const newArr3 = mockData.split(re3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr3))
```

Comment: @mplungjan the errant newline is because the engine matches `$` at that location, without any extra whitespace. So, it literally splits *at* the end of line which is *before* the newline character. The next split is because it matches `^\s*` at `with...` - there are *no* whitespace characters, so it satisfies the regex for `^`.